# Symmetric and definite positive matrix - complex vs real coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Let $M$ be a symmetric square matrix with complex coefficients, such that its imaginary part $N$ is positive definite.

Is it true that
$$A := {^t M} N^{-1} \overline M $$
has real coefficients?
(Here $^t M=M$ by symmetry).

I tested a random example, it seems [to work](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=transpose(%7B%7B2%2Bi,%201-i%7D,%7B1-i,%203%2B2i%7D%7D)%20*%20%7B%7B1,%20-1%7D,%7B-1,%202%7D%7D%5E(-1)%20%20*%20%7B%7B2-i,%201%2Bi%7D,%7B1%2Bi,%203-2i%7D%7D). But writing the $ij$-coefficient of $A$ gives
$$\sum_{k,l}  (^t M)_{il} (N^{-1})_{lk} \overline M_{kj}$$
so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $M=S+iN$, where $S$ is the (symmetric) real part of $M$. Then
$$
A=M^TN^{-1}\overline{M}=MN^{-1}\overline{M}=(S+iN)N^{-1}(S-iN)=SN^{-1}S+N,
$$
which is real.